# What has changed between 14.04 and 16.04 regarding fstab mount order?

Tags: automount

My installation of Ubuntu 14.04 has an `/etc/fstab` which mounts one line at a time, and the order is important for my application. I am now trialling 16.04, and it seems entries in fstab are now mounted randomly. What has changed, and how can I revert to the previous behaviour?

Comment: Can you add the contents of your `/etc/fstab`?

Answer (score 0):

"One option is to postpone mounting until after /etc/fstab has completed, this gives you full control over the mount order."
[How can I specify the order in which filesystems are automatically mounted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40185/how-can-i-specify-the-order-in-which-filesystems-are-automatically-mounted)